# If I drill holes in a door, would I then at a later time be able to conceal them reasonably well?

Tags: woodworking, patch

I have an over-the-door organizer in my pantry. It's about 5 feet tall and composed of three joined sections.

Problem is—since it has breaks on the vertical supports—it is wobbly.  When I open the door it moves just a little bit more slowly; when I close the door it wants to keep going after latching the door. Whenever it moves, half of its contents fall off, which is undesirable.

I want to put moly bolts in the door (hollow core) and affix the rack to the door to tighten it up a bit. I've been given the go ahead *only if I can be sure that I can semi-convincingly patch the holes if we remove the rack*. So is this something that it's possible to do? My first instinct if it were drywall would be to just use spackle and paint it, but obviously that won't work on a woodgrain door.

**Edit:** Based on the implied difficulty of doing what I wanted to do I opted for command strips. Originally that wouldn't have worked as the door rack is composed of modular shelf rails like the one pictured below, ergo a very small surface area for the command straps to stick to. I wound up JB-welding a metal plate to the back of the rails to increase the applicable surface area while still allowing for the locking mechanism of the shelving space.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try some 3M removable [command strips](http://www.command.com/3M/en_US/command/hooks-strips/) instead.  It's unlikely you will be able to conceal holes in your door.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the door?

Comment: @mmathis Unfortunately I asked on my lunchbreak at work, but will post a picture this evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better options to attach temporarily fixtures.  I would first try using 3M Command Strips to secure the organizer to the door.  In this way you can easily take it down without drilling holes in your door.  They also make velcro so you can remove the organizer and put it back later if you wish.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No. Or maybe yes.

Replicating wood grain even in painted wood or synthetic wood is very difficult. If you create holes large enough for togglers (3/8" minimum), you'll almost certainly need to sculpt the grain channels into the wood filler. If you're a crafty person, it can be done.

Of course you'll likely need to paint the entire door face to achieve a good blend.